# C++14 cURLcpp Submitting a form

Tags: c++, libcurl, c++14

I am trying to use [cURLcpp (not cURLpp)](https://github.com/JosephP91/curlcpp) to submit a form. In the readme there is an example of how to send a form request. Here is my code:

```
const std::string authenticityToken = stringMatch.substr(7, stringMatch.length());

curl::curl_form form;
curl::curl_easy easy;
// Forms creation
curl::curl_pair<CURLformoption,std::string> nameForm(CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "username");
curl::curl_pair<CURLformoption,std::string> nameCont(CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "the username");

curl::curl_pair<CURLformoption,std::string> passForm(CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "password");
curl::curl_pair<CURLformoption,std::string> passCont(CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "the password");

curl::curl_pair<CURLformoption,std::string> authForm(CURLFORM_COPYNAME,"authenticityToken");
curl::curl_pair<CURLformoption,std::string> authCont(CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, authenticityToken);

try {
    // Form adding
    form.add(nameForm, nameCont);
    form.add(passForm, passCont);
    form.add(authForm, authCont);

    // Add some options to our request
    easy.add<CURLOPT_URL>("https://account.mojang.com/login");
    easy.add<CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER>(false);
    easy.add<CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION>(1L);
    easy.add<CURLOPT_HTTPPOST>(form);
    // Execute the request.
    easy.perform();
} catch (curl::curl_easy_exception error) {
    // If you want to get the entire error stack we can do:
    curl::curlcpp_traceback errors = error.get_traceback();
    // Otherwise we could print the stack like this:
    error.print_traceback();
    // Note that the printing the stack will erase it
}
```

I get this error when compiling:

```
C:\Users\Czarek\ClionProjects\Learning\main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, const char**)':
C:\Users\Czarek\ClionProjects\Learning\main.cpp:40:40: error: no matching function for call to 'curl::curl_easy::add(curl::curl_form&)'
         easy.add<CURLOPT_HTTPPOST>(form);
```

Now, I followed the example like it was outlined on github? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Turns out that the tutorial on the website is a little bit wrong. The `easy.add<OPT>(value)` function accepts a curl_httpost variable. To get it from the `curl_form` you have to do `form.get()`. But to pass it to the `easy.add()` function you have to remove the const with `const_cast`. I believe this is just a bug in the library.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that `curl_easy` class does not have any version of `add()` which accepts `curl_form`. Looks like only add() variants it has are for CURLOption.

Comment: Alright, I am just starting off with C++ so I am not completely sure what to do here. Since the example in the readme shows that this is the proper way to do it. So how would I go ahead and do it properly?